# Image is shaking with onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'cant solve my problem with quaking image on mouseover. I have the following script:

```js
      function displayText(id)
      {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        el.style.display = 'block';
      }

      function hideText(id)
      {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        el.style.display = 'none';
      }
```

```css
.btn {
    margin-top: -90px;
    z-index: 999999999;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background: #37a000;
    displa: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' >
<img class="streamer_img" alt="example" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature"
onmouseover="this.src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'; displayText('hiddentext')" 
onmouseout="this.src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature'; hideText('hiddentext')" />
<p class="btn" id="hiddentext" style="display: none;">Watch/play</p>
</a>
```

Everything is fine but when I move my mouse over the displayed Watch text everything starts to shake.

How can I solve this trouble? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because when you hover over the `Watch` element it triggers the `mouseout` event on the `img` which changes the image. That in turn hides the text, which triggers the `mouseover` which shows the image... and so on infinitely.

To fix this you can instead attach the event handlers to the parent `a` element and find the `img` element within that to amend it, like this:

```js
function displayText(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideText(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.btn {
  margin-top: -90px;
  z-index: 999999999;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: #37a000;
  displa: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' onmouseenter="this.getElementsByClassName('streamer_img')[0].src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'; displayText('hiddentext')" onmouseleave="this.getElementsByClassName('streamer_img')[0].src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature'; hideText('hiddentext')">
  <img class="streamer_img" alt="example" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
  <p class="btn" id="hiddentext" style="display: none;">Watch/play</p>
</a>
```

Note that I changed the event handlers to `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` for better performance.

However you should note that using `on*` event attributes is awfully outdated. You should be using unobtrusive event handlers instead, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var a = document.querySelector('a');
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  var p = document.querySelector('p');

  a.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    img.src = a.dataset.hoversrc;
    p.style.display = 'block';
  });
  
  a.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    img.src = a.dataset.leavesrc;
    p.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin-top: -90px;
  z-index: 999999999;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: #37a000;
  displa: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' data-hoversrc="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" data-leavesrc="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
  <img class="streamer_img" alt="example" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
  <p class="btn" id="hiddentext" style="display: none;">Watch/play</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mate! Awesome solution.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I updated it with a better approach for you too.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, you're right regarding the outdated solution, my bad. And thanks again for a brief guide!